# How can I set up AdWhirl in the Android SDK?

Tags: android, adwhirl

The AdWhirl instructions are **extremely** crappy. All I want to know is how to set up the layout XML and get the source code into the Java of my application.

Can someone please give me an example for, let's say, a simple application with just buttons and text and pictures with the AdWhirl ads on the page?

Comment: doesn't seem that bad: https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/android/AdWhirlAndroidSDKSetup.html but I've used AdMob and that seemed easier to set up.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest working with [Admob Mediation](http://mediation.admob.com/) as that contains a more up to date development of Adwhirl. Adwhirl is actually developed in some part by Admob and so has been neglected with the release of Admob Mediation.

Look [at this link](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2423687) to see how Admob relates to Adwhirl and works with multiple banner ads. Admob implementation also has a lot more documentation online. Make sure you have an account already.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the answer' did not know the context of the question.
I was recently stumped about this when developing with the adwhirl server.

So incase anyone else is curious:

```
1) Install a firephp plugin in your favorite browser
2) update to latest version of FirePHP
3) refresh your page
4) have fun
```